# 2 Fields Added Together Do Not Add My Decimal Places

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a webpage and i on this page i have a 1 dropdown and 3 fields:

1. Payment type
2. Amount
3. Fee
4. Total amount

My 'Amount' field is editable and my 'Fee' fields reads a value from my web.config file as there are 2 different fees depending on the option selected from the dropdown.

But my 'Total' field does not seem to add in my decimal places and i need it to and both these fields are set up as `type="number"`.

All my code is below

**Web.config**

```
<!-- BACS Fee -->
<add key="BacsFee" value="25.00" />
<!-- Chaps Fee -->
<add key="ChapsFee" value="50.00" />
```

**View**

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4 control-label">Payment method</label>
     <div class="col-sm-4"><%: Html.DropDownList("PaymentMethod_DropDownList", paymentMethods, new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = "showModal(ChapsModal)" } )%></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4 control-label">Amount</label>
     <div class="col-sm-4"><%:Html.PrefixedTextBox("£", "OneOffPayment_Textbox", oneOffDefault, new { })%></div>
     <div class="col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-7" id="OneOffPaymentValidation"><%:Html.ValidationMessage("OneOffPayment_Textbox")%></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4 control-label">Fee</label>    
     <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="input-group">
               <span class="input-group-addon">£</span>
               <div id="BacsFee">
                    <input id="BacsFee_Textbox" type="number" class="form-control" value="<%= BacsFee %>" disabled>
               </div>
               <div id="ChapsFee">
                    <input id="ChapsFee_Textbox" type="number" class="form-control" value="<%= ChapsFee %>" disabled>
               </div>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4 control-label">Total amount</label>
     <div class="col-sm-4"><%:Html.PrefixedTextBoxWithId("£", "TotalAmount_Textbox", "TotalAmount_Textbox", "", new { }, true)%></div>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
function showModal(modal) {
        var selectedModal = '#' + modal.id;
        var e = document.getElementById("PaymentMethod_DropDownList");
        if (e.options[e.selectedIndex].text == 'CHAPS')
        {            
            $(selectedModal).modal('show');
            $('#ChapsFee').show();
            $('#BacsFee').hide();
        }
        else
        {
            $('#ChapsFee').hide();
            $('#BacsFee').show();
        }
    }

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#OneOffPayment_Textbox").keyup(function()
    {
        var val1 = parseInt($("#OneOffPayment_Textbox").val());
        var val2 = parseInt($("#BacsFee_Textbox").val());
        $("#TotalAmount_Textbox").val(val1 + val2);
    });
 });
```

Comment: use `parseFloat` for decimal like `parseFloat($("#OneOffPayment_Textbox").val());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you're parsing the provided value to integers which do not have floating points. Use `parseFloat()` instead:

```
$("#OneOffPayment_Textbox").keyup(function() {
    var val1 = parseFloat($("#OneOffPayment_Textbox").val());
    var val2 = parseFloat($("#BacsFee_Textbox").val());
    $("#TotalAmount_Textbox").val(val1 + val2);
});
```

If you require the result to be rounded to two decimal places, use `toFixed(2)`:

```
$("#TotalAmount_Textbox").val((val1 + val2).toFixed(2));
```

Comment: Perfect.  I was just about to ask about always adding 2 decimal places but your update beat me to it.  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

use `parseFloat` for decimal like `parseFloat($("#OneOffPayment_Textbox").val());`

> The parseFloat() function parses a string argument and returns a floating point number.